# PHP stored files in database are corrupted

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to create a platform where users are able to store files in database. I think the problem is that I'm not inserting correctly the files inside the database, because whenever I download them I cannot open.

My structure of database consists in the following:

```
ID        -> INT
file      -> LongBlob (I need to insert files at least at maximum with 10MB)
file_name -> Varchar
file_type -> Varchar
file_size -> Varchar
```

To insert the files, here's the mysqli code:

```
$_fileName = $_FILES['myfile']['name']; 
$_fileTmp  = $_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'];
$_fileType = $_FILES['myfile']['type'];
$_fileSize = $_FILES['myfile']['size'];
$_file     = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES[0]['tmp_name']));
$query = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO files (file, file_name, file_type, file_size)
                                      VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
/*
    b = blob
    s = string
*/
$query->bind_param("bsss", $_file, $_fileName, $_fileType, $_fileSize);
$query->execute();
```

I do believe this is correct, but..
Finally, to download the files I use:

```
header("Content-length:" . $file['file_size']);
header("content-type:" .   $file['file_type']);
header("Content-disposition: download; filename=" . $file['file_name']);

echo $file['file'];
```

Although when I download the file and try to open its corrupted (like .rar files, or zip files).
Also, I tried with .txt files and comes all empty..what can it be?

Thanks.

**Edit**: I do obviously know that storing in the disk is better than storing in the database. However, in this case, I cannot store in the disk simply because other users can not have the permission to access to it. If people, for some reason, guessed the name of the file they could download (like an image), and that's is why I'm storing in the database to avoid that.

I have also removed `addslashes()` but it continues to the file being corrupted.

**Edit - SOLVED**

The problem was on my `bind_param()`.
[The documentation of mysqli_stmt::bind-param](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) says the the 'b' stands for Blob BUT it will be sent in packets. Which, I believe, that condition was messing things up.

All I had to do was to change from 'b' to 's' (string) in my `bind_param()`.

```
$query->bind_param("ssss", $_file, $_fileName, $_fileType, $_fileSize);
```

Comment: Why are you calling to addslashes? As far as I understand, the file_get_contents function return the content of the file, isn't it? Calling the addslashes function you are corrupting file contents. You must insert the file "as is", without transforming it.

Comment: Better store the file on disc and put a reference into the database.

Answer (score 3):

*Comments have shown that the issue is not corrupted data, as the original question asserted, but the fact that the data is not stored in the database in the first place. The answer changes accordingly.*

You're storing blobs with `bind_param`. Instead, you're expected to use `send_long_data`. According to [a comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#110201) in `bind-param` documentation:

> if one has specified 'b' in $types, the corresponding variable should be set to null, and one has to use mysqli_stmt::send_long_data() or mysqli_stmt_send_long_data() to send the blob, otherwise the blob value would be treated as empty.

This means that the actual:

```
$_file = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES[0]['tmp_name']));
$query = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO files
                       (file, file_name, file_type, file_size)
                       VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$query->bind_param("bsss", $_file, $_fileName, $_fileType, $_fileSize);
$query->execute();
```

should be:

```
$query = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO files
                           (file, file_name, file_type, file_size)
                           VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$query->bind_param("bsss", NULL, $_fileName, $_fileType, $_fileSize);
$query->send_long_data(0, file_get_contents($_FILES[0]['tmp_name']));
$query->execute();
```

### Additional notes

1. [`addslashes`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) returns a string with backslashes before characters that need to be escaped. For example:

   ```
   "select * from User where UserName = '" . $userName . "'"
   ```

   would present a risk of SQL Injection if passed as-is to the database, since if the user name is `"'; drop table User; '"`, the executed query would be:

   ```
   select * from User where UserName = ''; drop table User; ''
   ```

   `addslashes` would be used to avoid the attack:

   ```
   "select * from User where UserName = '" . addslashes($userName) . "'"
   ```

   gives:

   ```
   select * from User where UserName = '\'; drop table User; \''
   ```

   Similarly, parametrized queries make it impossible to do SQL Injection by transforming special characters. This means that when the user name is passed as a parameter, it is treated as data, not as a part of a query. Since you're adding slashes before passing the value as a parameter, this means that you're actually storing the backslashes, thus corrupting the data.
2. Why are you storing 10 MB files in MySQL? The general solution is to store files on disk, not in a RDBMS.

   - Receiving a file would be as simple as copying/moving one from temporary directory to the specific one.
   - Sending the files to the user would also be easy with functions such as [`fpassthru`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fpassthru.php).
3. Why are you storing the size of files as `varchar()`, while it's an integer?

Comment: I thought the same, why is he inserting the files in the DB?. But he could have a couple of reasons: the first is the reference integrity. The file always exists with the record in the DB. http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Storing-Images-in-MySQL-with-PHP.html

Comment: @YourCommonSense: I haven't used PHP for a while and don't see what's so wrong with it. Please, may you take a few seconds explaining what's wrong with my answer and to tell whether it can be edited or should be simply removed? Thank you.

Comment: @MainMa, 1. read my edited post ; 2. It's not the varchar problem. ; 3. I thank you for the explanation about `addslashes()`, but it's not the `addslashes()` fault either. I removed it and still does not work.

When I download the file it comes corrupted.

Comment: @user3355243: your edit about the security issue is wrong: you have simply to store the files outside the directories served by the web server.

Comment: @user3355243: is the data in the database matching the file? This will help finding if the problem is at the stage where you store the file, or at the stage where you send it to the user.

Comment: @MainMa I went to the database and, unfortunately, the file is not being saved correctly with that code. The field 'file' has the following: `[BLOB - 0 Bytes]`. Which means the problem starts in the insert..however the rest of the fields such as `file_name`, `file_size` and `file_type` is totally correct.

Comment: What about using [`send_long_data()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.send-long-data.php)?

Comment: To use that I would need to exceed the size limit. Although I have a function to check if exceeds or not. Also, I have, in .htacess the following: `php_value post_max_size 10M`
`php_value upload_max_filesize 10M` the files I'm sending for the server (for testing purposes) does not exceeds 1kb, such like images.

Comment: And, btw, I'm sending the files through ajax, and you might ask if that files are really be sent and the answer is yes, otherwise it wouldn't get the name, type or size of it. Plus, I use the `ChromePhp::logger' extension to debug purposes. You can see an image exemplifying that. http://s27.postimg.org/4w9xiq6hf/Sem_t_tulo.jpg

Comment: @user3355243: I'm glad that it helped. This being said, even if your code works now, don't ignore my suggestion of storing files on disk instead of RDBMS, especially since the only argument you gave against it appears to be invalid.

Comment: @MainMa I have asked the other user how do I manage to insert files into my ftp and disable access to it to any user logged or not in. He thought I was asking for reading the file path from database...

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot store in the disk simply because other users can not have the permission to access to it. If people, for some reason, guessed the name of the file they could download (like an image), and that's is why I'm storing in the database to avoid that.

This is a mere delusion. Of course, filesystem can offer the same level of security. Nobody forces you to store files within the web root. You can store them above, making direct access impossible. As simple as that.

Comment: Can you reference any tutorial of how to achieve that?

Comment: I doubt there is any tutorial on such a basic thing. instead of reading your file from database, just read it from the file. That's all